# Monitor Execution Time for click event handlers in DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiler

How can I, using the Chrome DevTools JavaScript Profiler, measure the amount of time taken for an event handler (a click for example) to finish executing?

I'm trying to compare the execution time of my event handler before and after using the `OnPush` Change Detection Strategy offered by Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a Performance recording to get a rough estimate of how the long the listener takes to execute. General workflow is:

1. Start recording.
2. Click the button (or whatever) in order to trigger the listener.
3. Stop recording. See [Get Started With Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=2018Q1) to get familiar with the recording UI.
4. Find the listener in the [Main thread activity chart](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#main).
5. Click on the listener to view its details in the Summary tab (the section in the "Main thread activity chart" also explains the Summary tab). From here you can see how the long listener took to execute.

You can also instrument your app with the [User Timing API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/). You can either log the measurements to the Console, or look at them in a Performance recording. DevTools automatically logs User Timing measurements to the Main thread activity chart.